Can anyone win a "game" of Rocket Tag on an interstellar level against a prepared opponent?
Relativistic Kinetic Kill Vehicles (RKKVs) are all but undetectable until it's far too late to do anything about them; they have a very low radiation profile once at cruising velocity, their exhaust plume is also, by definition, pointed away from the target while accelerating. They're almost impossible to intercept at cruising speed because once you can detect them they're not there any more; that close to c any signal lag kills your ability to track them. And they're, relatively, cheap compared to weapons that do less damage with more precision.
Several answers to this question suggest that warfare in settings where settlements are disparate and thinly connected stand a good chance of turning into an interstellar Rocket Tag scenario in which any time anyone fires a shot it destroys a star system wholesale. When I asked the question I didn't have a clear mental image of what that might look like; then this year I read The Killing Star

which opens with the almost total destruction of humanity over the course of a few hours by an interstellar civilisation using a system wide relativistic kinetic bombardment.

The parallels to another scenario in the universe of the above question made me think about the fact that anyone who knows their enemies have the capability to fire such weapons, and matches it, can still retaliate, possibly even after everyone is dead. They can leave RKKVs cold in space until the incoming munitions have committed to targets, or even until after they've hit, these undetectable arms can then take a bearing on possible source stars for the attack and hit back. Possibly they even simply target all neighbouring star systems in case someone got clever with the vectors.
To me, at first blush, this situation appears to be a clean cut case of MAD, and even a classic case in the political sense as well if everyone knows that everyone is armed. So, apart from an asymmetric case like that in The Killing Star wherein an actor fires on someone who is unable to launch their own relativistic munitions, can one win at interstellar Rocket Tag?
Edit for clarity
Universe specific information; High relativistic speeds (greater than 0.90c) are commonplace, near neighbours stay in sporadic contact trading in IP, read new tech designs and artworks, is common, physical goods are not. Transportation of colonists and labourers outward from overpopulated systems occurs regularly but tourism is virtually nonexistent. Polities encompassing whole solar systems are common and larger, but rather theoretical, leagues do exist kept together by digital diplomatic packets rather than physical embassies. Any ship moving between worlds can and does act as a spy, by deliberately investigating particular issues for a fee and/or just by selling their sensor records at new ports for those who want to catch up on the news from abroad.

Is this a universe with no FTL?  If so, how much interaction occurs between the inhabitants orbiting different stars?

What are their territories like size-wise (a galactic map might help)? What's their knowledge like of each other's territories? What resources are available to each civ - how fast can they build weapons? What exactly is the capability of the specified weapons? Do you want one civ to be capable of ending the war for good?

Can we assume you're ignoring the trivial answer of - someone just stops play by not tagging back?

Are you asking about the novel?

@elemtilas No it simply demonstrates the principle.

@KerrAvon2055 I was thinking about a universe where travel at high relativistic velocities is common but no FTL so contact is sporadic, no bulk trade, tourism is pretty rare etc...

@Escapeddentalpatient. Who's going to stop a game that's set to play itself in the event that the builder is dead?

Just for clarity... so it's not like tag. (I've not come across the book you're referring to.) Any race (Asgardians in Stargate SG1) might decide to quit and end it all.

You might want to clarify by deleting the reference to someone else's work, then. As you know, we only answer your questions about your own work here!

@Escapeddentalpatient. The term Rocket Tag comes from computer games, it refers to any situation in which everyone is armed with weapons powerful enough that any hit is an automatic kill.

@elemtilas Demonstrably untrue but I've reworked the question.

I see two big problems with this setup. First is that shotgunning a solar system to kill a planet is roughly equivalent to machine gunning every square centimeter of a football field to kill a single bacterium. It's hard to see how it could ever be worth it. The second is that you really can't have a science-based civilization that can throw that kind of mass and energy around that still cares about old-fashioned things like planets. You're going to need a whole planet worth of matter just for your projectiles.

I don't have a complete answer, but would a Nicoll-Dyson Laser change the defense much?

Is it even conceivable to be able to hit a tiny planet over light years of distance? The accuracy of interstellar coordinates and vectors needed is astronomical. If you can do that, maybe there's a lot more you can also do that completely removes the threat.

@DonQuiKong You can spare a little mass for maneuvering to final target, hitting the system is easier.

@gs Given how much more fragile a constructed habitat is compare to a big solid ball of rock you need very little mass to explosively deconstruct one.

Be a Moving Target
Any star system can be targeted so the solution is to not be at any star system.
If you were in artificial world ships travelling through the empty space between stars or even between galaxies, they can't hit you.
Throw in random path wandering and their chances of hitting are virtually zero as space is really really big.

So throwing the first punch from outside the established polity system? Nice.

also, use self-replicating ships, along with self-replicating crews to simply outgrow any attempt at being eradicated.

@Going Durden Last time I checked, humans were already self replicating......

@Thorne sure, but it might be faster if they used stuff like uterine tanks and cloning batches to amplify the process. We don't knwo the exact timeline here; do they have 20 years before the war starts, or 2000?

Do not play the game or detect early
There are two ways to win. First is not to play the game. You see that with the nuclear standoff. Any move that entails actually firing a missile leads to an escalation that reduces the warring nations to nothing, and probably much more collateral. And do you want a remaining country like Luxembourg take over the world? I think not.
Detect early
The second way can reduce your enemy to dust, while staying out of harms way. The RKKVs are going 0.9C (maybe faster?), which means you can communicate faster than the RKKVs. That, plus the huge distances, gives you time. Next to the RKKVs you launch, you launch detection satellites. They will position at several distances between you and the target, beaming information back at the speed of light. These have a good chance to detect the enemy RKKVs, as they float in deep space with little distorting sources. Even if they don't detect the RKKVs before they pass, they certainly do after from the plume or sheer proximity and/or active detection mechanisms.
That means you can beam information about where they are back to your defences. If you know when and how they are coming, they can be nudged out of position or destroyed. With the galactic distances what they are, you can have a good time to react. There's probably good ways when and how to launch with certain expected speeds and when positions of the RKKVs are still reliable from detection. A way to detect them at A, then when they are detected again at B for their exact positions your anti-RKKV measures should be right there to take care of it.
That being said, having communication reach you and you only have 10% of the time left to react can make anyone nervous. If you can truly nudge them out of position or destroy them on time depends a lot on how far the systems are apart.  To truly nip this in the bud, you want to destroy them when the enemies RKKVs start accelerating. When your RKKVs arrive, you should already have secondary small RKKVs that arrive later, that are able to detect and adjust their trajectory to impact enemy RKKVs before they pose any danger.
To do that correctly, probably you want a long line of detection satellites that pass through the enemy star system at intervals from the moment your RKKVs hit until your counter wave arrives, each communicating any possible RKKVs.
Information war
The question then becomes why this isn't done in the first place. Placing any detectors between you and the enemy can assist you with detection and possible evasion of annihilation. The same is true for moving your population with huge star ships. Likely both sides will try to monitor the situation, detecting any movement and adjusting the RKKVs accordingly. Eventually this can be resolved in only two ways. One is to not play the game, the other is to defeat the detection in any way possible. Destruction, obfuscation, confusion, hacking, overwhelming by sheer number if RKKVs or whatever.
My bet would be not to play. The advantages of using so much energy to destroy a potential opponent seem minimal compared to using it for expansion of any form. The danger is simply too high to play.

You can't actually communicate over interstellar distances at light speed with any known technology, otherwise detection would be a great idea, even if hitting a RKKV is still very hard once it gets moving. You might be able to gravity tractor them with enough warning though. Hitting them during the earliest stage of acceleration would be ideal but I can't see launching enough ordinance to saturate a retaliation force, you miss one and "It's game over man, game over". My money is on the side of don't play too, like I said it feels like a MAD situation.

@Ash "You can't actually communicate over interstellar distances at light speed with any known technology": there's numerous possible ways to do so. And hitting a RKKV is just a matter of getting in its path, the advantage is on the interceptor's side due to the delta-v required to significantly alter the RKKV's path to evade and then get back on target, and its own limitations in ability to track the smaller, slower interceptors lurking along its path.

"Even if they don't detect the RKKVs before they pass, they certainly do after from the plume or sheer proximity and/or active detection mechanisms." - What plume? If it's coming from interstellar distances, it's finished accelerating well before entering enemy territory, and it's not like there's a medium for it to disrupt. It's also questionable how close it would need to get to any detectors; space is really big [Adams 1979]. If the detectors are far enough out to be useful, they have a lot of surface area to cover if they want to catch everything crossing that radius.

@Ray at those speeds, even the relative  vacuum of space will create a very bright plasma envelope meaning that even at a coast, you are a very hot, bright object... and to maintain those speeds, you need constant acceleration to overcome resistance.

It's worth mentioning that interception does not require a fast moving missile, just enough precision to get in the RKKV's path. If the closest star is 4ly away, 10% of that is about 5 months to react.  That is a lot of time to track a distant object and plan an intercept path, the final actual interception might only need a few minutes to move an interceptor into the RKKV's path.

@Nosajimiki Merely intercepting a RKKV just gives you a larger, slightly-slower RKKV. You have to hit it sideways hard, and far away, so angles do the hard work for you. You have substantially less than 5 months to react.

@ChristopherJamesHuff No known means of signal transmission works over light years without losing signal cohesion and/or focus to the point of noise. And hitting a RKKV is just going to turn it into relativistic shrapnel, not a winning plan.

@wizzwizz4 Yeah that's why I figured gravity tractors were the way to go.

Both radio and lasers can transmit useful amounts of information over light years, it isn't even very difficult with laser comms. And gravity tractors require you to hold position in proximity to the target for a prolonged period of time while tugging on it with the weakest of the fundamental forces, the only way you'd even begin to make it work is by launching the interceptor from the same system the RKKV originated from.

@ChristopherJamesHuff Radio blurs out within a light-year, lasers start to lose coherence in the space of light minutes and turn into giant lighthouse illustration style cones, the best range I know of is from UREBs and even those bloom eventually. You don't need a lot of deflection and you really can't afford to shatter an RKKV so you need an option that isn't just shooting them down.

Radio does not "blur out within a light year", and lasers easily span interstellar distances with a fraction of the power requirements and far smaller reflectors. Even the tiny little laser comms package on the Psyche probe is capable of a high data rate transfer across multiple AU. UREB...electron beams? Those would be totally useless for communication. And no, an RKKV will not "shatter", even a small impact will vaporize one. Only a small fraction will then hit its target, and even that will be spread over more time, vastly reducing the effects.

@wisswiss4 You wouldn't need to hit it like that I don't think. Simply setting up a sufficiently large Whipple type shield will obliterate the projectile, rendering it pretty much harmless.

@wizzwizz4 Bubbles is correct.  When the RKKV hits an interceptor the difference in relative speeds would cause a significant matter to energy conversion comparable to a nuclear bomb.  Even though the RKKV still has a significant amount of momentum in the original direction, its remaining mass will now be radiating out in every direction at relativistic speeds so all that will hit your planet will be a wave of highly dispersed radiation that will be absorbed absorbed by your planet's magnetosphere and upper atmosphere.

@Nosajimiki That could disperse a planet-killing RKKV, but I doubt it could disperse a star-system-killing RKKV enough. It'd be radiating out in all directions from the perspective of an inertial frame comoving with the centre-of-mass of the combined system, but that inertial frame would still be heading towards your star system at relativistic velocities.

@wizzwizz4 You can't kill a star system with a RKKV.  Even under highly idealized scenarios, RKKVs are only a couple of orders of magnitude more powerful than nukes... but in practice they are probably less powerful once you account for all the ejection mass and energy it actually takes to get up to those speeds.  Unless these things are really big, you probably need a few thousand just to cause an effective planetary extinction event.

@wizzwizz4 I believe the OP is proposing a salvo of RKKVs that hit all the planets in a starsystem, not 1 RKKV that can destroy a star in which case the solution is simply to launch multiple interceptors to break up multiple RKKVs

let me quote a supercomputer that ran into the same problem when playing Thermonuclear War: The only winning move is not to play.

@Nosajimiki You might be able to kill a star system with an RKKV by targeting the star.

@LorenPechtel Stars are much harder to explode than you might think.  A 0.9c RKKV capable of overcoming the sun's binding energy would need to be about 60% more massive than the Earth. Even if you have the tech to accelerate a Super Earth to 0.9c, It's is a stupid number or orders of magnitude less wasteful to just to bombard the entire surface of every inhabited planet no matter what your actual tech level is.

Even if you have a dyson sphere, it would take 10s of millions of years to collect enough power to make a star destroying RKKV.  Better to just wait for your enemy to die of natural causes.

@Nosajimiki Not to blow it up--if you have that kind of energy you're not bothering with RKKVs.  I'm talking about slamming something into the envelope hard enough to temporarily cause fusion.  Really nasty flare.

@LorenPechtel but you'd need to create enough fusion to engulf the whole star system in every direction. You'd still need something in the mass range of a planet to do that.

@Nosajimiki I can't remember the size of object I saw mentioned but it was small asteroid size, not planet size.

@LorenPechtel To make a directed flare able to consume a single planet perhaps... but not to make an omni-directional nova capable of consuming the whole solar system.

@Nosajimiki I'm not thinking of consuming it, just wrecking an awful lot of stuff.  If you're capable of throwing RKKVs you have extensive space infrastructure which is unlikely to withstand the mother of all flares.  Few if any direct kills, a nightmare trying to rebuild stuff before things come apart to the point they can't.  Think of what a Carrington Event would do to present day Earth, just much, much bigger.  Planet, so what.  People--I'm not sure civilization would survive.

Let's start with a few assumptions:
The belligerents hate each other. The reasons for that are quite unclear because by nature of having no trade relations and no immigration, I don't really see a way for conflict to ever escalate to "we'll glass your homeworld" levels. Let's just say that they do hate each other and would glass each other, were it not for MAD doctrine.
Almost everyone lives on, or in orbit of, a planet susceptible to be completely destroyed. This is a given because logistics dictate so: you need to get power somehow, and space is full of a whole lot of nothing, so solar needs you to be close to a sun (potential target), nuclear requires you get isotopes from a world, not even thinking about actual supplies.
Under these principles, you're right that this is a classic example of MAD. Unless you can find a way to stop these RKKVs in-flight, which is impossible, as a potential target, you need to set up a counter-strike force in deep interstellar space, and either commit mass genocide as collateral damage or have it accurately target whoever killed you (not that it really matters. If you're hit you're dead anyway, nobody is going to prosecute you for war crimes).
As I see it, the only way to change this dynamic is by changing the assumptions. Either you manage to negotiate peace under MAD (just like on current-day Earth), and your problem isn't really resolved, or:
You move everyone away from targets. The system-wide government enacts a plan where they launch the RKKVs, then after that (so that it is impossible to see happen remotely until the weapons have already hit), you have all the travel time of the weapons to put everyone on ships, and send them into deep space to live lives as voidborns, where they're untargetable because your enemies can't learn where they're going until after the weapons hit.
The problem essentially boils down to "what can we do to make the enemy unable to target us until after the first strike?" and one answer is arcologies. Another answer, depending on your technology level, is to alter the orbit of targets, but at that technology level, the weapons could realistically make the local sun go nova and you're going to have trouble moving a sun.

Weirdly moving a star system wholesale might be easier than evacuating the population. See Stellar engines and in particular the Shkadov Thrusters

Stellar engines are slow, relative to a RKKV.

@PaŭloEbermann Yes but if you start it up once the RKKVs are committed it doesn't have to be fast, or even last too long to move the system off angle.

"We glass your Homeworld" could be triggered by one species being anathema to the other, such as one percieves the other as an existential threat due to how they procreate or as food. Think a species of sentient parasitic brain bugs that turn humanoids into shells or Tyranid/Xenomorphs that eat everything in the way

@Trish: sure, but they're light years away. in the absence of FTL, there's realistically nothing they could to to humans. not that it's important to this question anyway, but i wanted to point it out.

Place yourself on a relativistic vessel, that goes as fast as the RKKVs to always outrun or outmanouver them. A society of "spacers" who fly about and rarely stop except for refueling is impossible to target.
That, and make sure the Spacers use a form of Von Neumann-style self-replicating ships, and CLONE THEMSELVES along with their ships, so they become like an exponentially growing infection of the universe, impossible to eradicate with RKKVs, or any other realistic weapon for that matter.

Frame Challenge: You are grossly overestimating the effectiveness of RKKVs
First of all, an RKKV is going to be less powerful than the warheads that a civilization at a given tech level could conceivably design.  The only science-based way to get an RKKV up to 0.9c is through the expenditure of mass into energy which means you need to have a nuclear power source, account for all of its inefficiency, and then compound it by the inefficiency of your propulsion system.  So, if you assume your propulsion system is 70% efficient, then making a RKKV that can hit with 35 megatons of force will consume the same amount of fuel as a 50 megaton warhead made using the same tech level. So, even if your setting has the high efficiency anti-matter containment that would be needed for such high speeds, you should expect to need litteral tons of fuel and infrastructure for every kg to mass you want to get up to those speeds.
Furthermore, you can not make a RKKV into an accurate weapon for the same reasons hypersonic missile struggle so much with accuracy.  At those speeds, even against the relative vacuum of space, your RKKVs will run into enough matter to develop a plasma envelope that will blind the RKKV's sensors and communication systems meaning that once it is up to speed, its flying blind.  These missiles can't see thier environment to know how to make course corrections, and they can't possibly predict the exact "atmospheric conditions" of all of the space between two points to be able to precalculate an accurate trajectory.  So, if you were to try to launch one from one star system to another, you'd be lucky to even hit the goldilocks zone, much less an actual planet, much less an actual target on the planet.
This means that the only way to hit something as small as a planet is to fly into the solar system and slow down enough to lose you plasma envelope so you can see and make course corrections, then get close enough to the planet to be able to launch a much smaller secondary RKKV so that your can hit the planet... but unless your RKKVs can go from zero to 0.9c almost instantly, there may not be an actual distance where you have enough room to accelerate your weapon while still being target accurate... and target accuracy is important.  It would take 10,000s of nukes (or similar sized RKKVs) to actually depopulate an Earth sized world through random bombardment, but 100 or so well placed guided nuclear weapons could wipe out all of a planet's major city's sending the whole planet's economy into ruin neutralizing the planet's threat to you without having to fully wipe out its inhabitants.  So... all of this is to say that weather you want to use slow nukes or RKKVs, you need to get really close to a planet while moving at relatively low speeds to be able to attack it.
This gives the plant plenty of time to deploy a fleet to intercept you while you are trying to "slow boat" yourself into a good bombardment position.  Also, assuming the RKKVs need time to speed up, there will be a window of time where they are moving way less than 0.9c where you will have time to respond by shooting it down with long range lasers or launching interceptors to take them down before they can reach your world. This also takes away all of your presumptions that an RKKV might be a stealthy weapon because you have to wait until you are close to accelerate it.

MAD relied on the fact that both parties could survive in some form long enough to retaliate. It also relied on the fact that both parties could detect a nuclear strike ahead of time.
Point being, for MAD to work you need to be able to survive long enough to strike back.
A properly coordinated RKKV strike could kill every inkling of life in a solar system and every surrounding solar system simultaneously. Once you've fired, you can safely assume nobody is firing back.
Even if they have "cold" RKKVs waiting to fire off, as the name suggests, they're cold and therefore venerable, so just make some of your RKKVs into relativistic canister shot. Shower the entire solar system with relativistic shrapnel before the main show to eliminate any nasty surprises.
Also I highly doubt they would be undetectable if they're stationary, to get an object up to relativistic speeds it needs ALOT of fuel and therefore a very large rocket. Even if your using antimatter, your still looking at a very large object presumably orbiting a star. Which then of course needs to start accelerating which takes time, even with the best fuels and optimal conditions there's still a fairly wide window where its vulnerable.
Also RKKVs aren't undetectable, in their dormant state they would likely be orbiting something, they would first have to escape that bodies gravity. That initial launch could be detected if you had the right equipment. For example if you were monitoring a solar system you've fired at.
RKKVs are extremely overpowered, the second we discover another intelligent civilization, its a race to see who can build an RKKV first.

Even converting your entire solar system, star included, into RKKV "canister shot" would probably not be enough to fully clear the target system. All but a microscopic portion of what you shoot at the target will pass through harmlessly. And there's no reason to assume the target's retaliatory RKKVs are in orbit in their system, it would take a tiny fraction of their propulsive capabilities to deploy them into nearby interstellar space, which could also be done with low-power propulsion systems that aren't detectable at interstellar distances.

Survival is not necessary to retaliate. For starters, a doomed party can detect a strike and retaliate before the initial strike hits. Even if that were somehow not possible, a dead-man setup allows retaliation after a party is dead. Finally, hiding even very large objects orbiting a star is almost trivial - just have them floating cold out in the Kuiper belt of the system.

"Presumably orbiting a star" - why?  That's like presuming that strategic planners in the cold war would have their missiles in population centres.  As soon as you decide to adopt this strategy, you put your RKKVs out in deep space where no one could possibly find them.  You don't clump them up; each new deployment goes somewhere else.  There's lots of space to hide in, and then if a dead man's hand retaliatory strike is necessary, it can't possibly be preempted by an opponent's first strike.

There is a small window wherein you could signal a retaliation (and it widens significantly if you try that shotgun thing) but you really don't need it with a dead man's switch. Large is relative at the scale of a solar system, you could hide hundreds of RKKVs behind a small asteroid, we have a lot of rocks floating around the solar system, never mind if you parked them within/behind comets out in the Kuiper Belt either way you don't need to worry about orbital escape.

@jdunlop You'd want them in orbit of the star, just not in the habitable zone, you still want them close enough to keep in touch with them, a dead man is either going to rely on a continuous signal or a signal send on delay, but you don't keep them where they might be collateral damage in a strike on a population centre.

@Ash there's no reason at all to have them in orbit. If you don't fire them up for their attack run, they'll stay nearby for millions of years even without any stationkeeping efforts. They just need to be close enough for a counterattack to be triggered, and for that they really just need to monitor their origin system for signatures of relativistic impacts, which are going to be both very distinct and identifiable from great distances.

@ChristopherJamesHuff Thanks, I'd been thinking in terms of needing to be in signal contact rather than passive sensors onboard.

@Gene
Technically yes a Deadman switch would work but its not fool proof, the Deadman switch still needs some way of knowing the home planet isn't dead. I think usually (The Russians) just broadcast some signal and if certain silos don't receive that signal for a certain length of time they launch. A similar system could be spoofed before or just after launching your RKKVs.
Once the signal is spoofed you can take your time locating and disarming the RKKVs once all the fireworks are done.

@ChellCPlus Spoofing is nigh-impossible with good cryptography, and straight-up impossible if the signal being broadcast is a one-time pad (and generating billions of years worth of random numbers is trivial even with our technology today.) And as ChristopherJamesHuff points out, you don't even need a signal in the first place.
